# ant ID montreal, qc canada

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'd like to know what type of ants this is. These appeared in my basement recently.

I am thinking those are called "pavement ants" after comparing online. Please help me identify them.

( Sorry for the blurry image quality, these are quite small and are scared of my camera )
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]